# Sending email using python and gmail

Tags: python, excel, email

I'm sending emails to my subscribers using python and gmail.

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

SenderAddress = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
password = "emailpass"

e = pd.read_excel("Email.xls")
emails = e['Emails'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(SenderAddress, password)
msg = """
email message
"""
subject = "Email Subject"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
server.quit()
```

My email list consists of 104 email address. When i run the code i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Website/bulkemail.py", line 49, in <module>
    server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 736, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 470, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 395, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 369, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I would like to know the reason for this error

I would like to know which emails were sent and which were not sent so i can try resending later.

Also i would like to know if this error has anything to do with the number of emails in the list

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to know which emails were sent and which were not sent*

I suggest to log actions you are doing, simple way is using text file, for example in your case you might do something like

```
with open("sent.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("===STARTING SENDING MAILS===\n")
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
    recipent_address = # here get that from email
    with open("sent.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(recipent_address + "\n")
```

which should result in file `sent.txt` holding addresses where mails were sent. If malfunction then happen just already processed recipents are after last `===STARTING SENDING MAILS===`.

*if this error has anything to do with the number of emails in the list*

Gmail has day limit of emails sent, from [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en#zippy=%2Cyou-have-reached-a-limit-for-sending-mail)

> You may see this message if you send an email to a total of more than
> 500 recipients in a single email and or more than 500 emails sent in a
> day.
>
> When you get this error, you should be able to send emails again
> within 1 to 24 hours.

Note that 104 is less 500 so if you did not send anything beyond single run of your code this should not be problem

Comment: Please also if you can help what causes this error and how to solve it?